# iPad Rotation lock problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, rotation

Hellow i have a question about the rotation on iPad i have search but i have not found the correct awnser.

in the iPad app i can rotate to all interface orientations when i open a special overlay i will lock the interface orientacion to lanscape and as long as the overlay is open the application should not rotate. When i close this overlay the rotation should be enabled.

i hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that. I have not tested this code, but I think it will work.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation     {
// Return YES for supported orientations.
       if (showing_OVERLAY == YES) {
            return NO;
       }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: thx that works i have test this befor i ask her but i have implemented that in the wrong viewController (in a subViewController) i must do this in the RootViewController than it works :-)

Comment: where exactly does this code go? appdelegate? views?

Comment: It goes in the ViewController of the class where you want the rotation to be disabled. eg- LoginViewController, if that is where you want the rotation to be disabled.